# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Id - SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am reading from my database performing an inner join clause in c#. Whenever it hits the line
`x.Id = (int)reader["Id"];` it says "**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Id**". I know that error displays when it does not exist in the db. But on ssms when I run the cmd

```
select ItemName
from MainStore
inner join SecondStore
on MainStore.Id = SecondStore.Id
```

which returns

```
ItemName

Candy

Marshmallow
```

In c# I do,

```
        List<MainStore> storeList = new();

        SqlConnection connection = new();

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ItemName from MainStore inner join SecondStore on MainStore.Id = SecondStore.Id", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var x = new MainStore();

                x.ItemName = reader["ItemName"].ToString();
                x.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                x.SecondStore.Id = (int)reader["Id"];

                storeList.Add(x);
            }

        }
```

both lines x.Id and x.SecondStore.Id give me the same error. Why is that?

```
public class MainStore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public SecondStore SecondStore { get; set; }
}

public class SecondStore
{
    public int SecondStoreId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As you've shown, the results only have the "ItemName" column, because that's all you've selected. Why would you expect `reader["Id"]` to be valid?

Comment: Yes, I only wanted ItemName. From reading this article https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp, I thought when translating the sql cmd to c# we would need to include that in the reader.read(). So in my situation, I would not need to do `x.Id` nor `x.SecondStore.Id` correct? @JonSkeet

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "we would need to include that in the reader.read()" - if you need the value, you should select it in the SQL. If you don't need the value, don't try to read it.

Comment: That makes alot more sense now. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query

```
"select ItemName, MainStore.Id as MainStoreId, SecondStore.Id as SecondStoreId from MainStore inner join SecondStore on MainStore.Id = SecondStore.Id", connection))
```

But I think  you have a bug in your query relations. Pls post the MainStore and the SecondStore classes.

and code

```
 x.ItemName = reader["ItemName"].ToString();
 x.Id = (int)reader["MainStoreId"];
```

SecondStore.Id is the same as MainStoreId. You will have to create then SecondStore object too, but I can't see why do you need it

Comment: Didn't think about using aliases good to know! Thank you for your help! Sorry yeah I realized there was an issue with my model class!